# workable solution for isolating development from production in DB2 z/OS

Tags: database, db2, production-environment, privileges, zos

I am a developer and I need to be able to create tables, triggers, view, functions, procedures, constraints, etc. for prototyping solutions for putting business logic rules into the database. My company has refused to allow me to install a local instance of LUW for this, and my DBAs have agreed to set up a sandbox on a corporate server. We are running into problems with both isolating my work from everything else and granting me privileges to create all the objects I need to prototype, and they are trying to do this within the same instance/subsystem as objects shared with clients. They have created a separate tablespace, but we are still running into trouble when I try to create a function that reads data which seems related to permissions within the WLM that I do not have.

On LUW, I would just tell them to create a separate database within the same instance, but I'm less familiar with z/OS, and database does not mean the same across the two platforms.

Is there an easy, logical equivalent to creating a separate LUW database that I could advise my DBAs to set up on the z system?

Comment: Why are you doing this on a production system?  Best practice is to do this sort of thing on a development system, ideally not even part of the same sysplex, and with dummy/old data.

Comment: Agreed, but that option was not given to me.  Sounds like a distinct subsystem for developers only is what is wanted.